# Updating value of bound property during PropertyChangedCallback

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

I have a situation where I need to intercept WPF's attempt to set the value of a property that's bound to a text box, and change the value that actually gets stored. Basically, I'm allowing the user to enter a complex value into a TextBox but parse it into components automatically.

Everything is working except I cannot get the UI to refresh and display the newly calculated value to the user.

**View Model**

```cs
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string serverName = string.Empty;

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  public string ServerName
  {
    get
    {
        return this.serverName;
    }
    set
    {
        this.serverNameChanged(value);
    }
  }

  private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
  {
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    {
      this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }

  private void serverNameChanged(string value)
  {
    if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(value, UriKind.Absolute))
    {
      var uri = new Uri(value);
      this.serverName = uri.Host;
      this.NotifyPropertyChanged("ServerName");

      // Set other fields and notify of property changes here...
    }
  }
}
```

**View**

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding ServerName}" />
```

When the user keys/pastes/etc. a full URL into the "server name" text box and tabs out, the view model code runs and all of the fields in the view model are set correctly. All of the *other* fields bound to the UI refresh and display. However, even though the `ServerName` property returns the correct value, the `Text` displayed on-screen is the old value.

Is there a way to force WPF to take my new property value and refresh the display while in the middle of the "source property changed" process?

**NOTE:**

I have also tried making `ServerName` a `DependencyProperty` and doing the work in an actual `PropertyChangedCallback` but the results are identical.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Does it work if you comment out all codes after NotifyPropertyChanged("ServerName")? Usually you can use Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=> this.NotifyPropertyChanged("ServerName"))) to achieve this.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the output window?

Comment: @BillZhang that actually worked (running the notification via the dispatcher); can you make that an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Bill Zhang, the way to achieve this is to run the `NotifyPropertyChanged` even through the dispatcher; this causes the event to run after the current event finishes, and updates the display correctly.

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
    this.NotifyPropertyChanged("ServerName")))
```